# Is it a bad model to have all settings pages to point to the same script to apply settings in PHP?

Tags: php, model, settings

The question is worded a bit strangely, but I couldn't figure out any other way. I'd like to know if there is a better model for doing this. Here's what I have now:

Say I'm editing a user on my application. I submit the form, and it POSTs to `apply.php?ref=edituser`. Then on `apply.php`, it has a large conditional to determine which settings are being submitted, based on the ref variable, at which point it runs that part of the script. If it succeeds or has an error, it uses `header("Location: uedit.php")` to return to the previous page, also setting `$_SESSION['err']` with the error code. That page checks to see if the error code is set, and displays and unsets it if it is.

I feel like I might have too much in a single script. Any opinions on this?

Comment: "POSTs to apply.php?ref=edituser"  is a error. A post can't have GET parameters. Some proxies will ate the non-standard get parameter in the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do multiple forms submit to it?

As a general rule a form doesn't submit to a model a form submits to a controller in the MVC structure.  The controller then decides how it should handle everything.  But if you comment everything well and don't think it is to much I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As I said, depends on style.  MVC is a style, not a requirement for PHP

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your style.  Website I'm working on only uses 2 main php files.  Only thing I would recommend is to make sure you comment well

Answer (score 0):

The cons with this kind of system is like mentioned before, it can be hard to keep track of all code in a logic way.

An other con is that php is an interpreted language which means that the whole file need to be parsed on each run. That means that if you separate the code into different files instead of building a big one you will gain performance. But of course, if it is not to big it won't matter.